# Can I write-off Visual Studio 2010 on my taxes if I want to learn it?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, taxes, education

I doubt I can write it off, but I just figured I'd check anyway.  What if I took a class in it and needed the software to take the class?

Comment: Are you self-employed, or a regular employee?

Comment: @Chris Presently I'm unemployed.  I'd like to be employed however, and I think learning .NET might help with that.

Comment: @leeand00 - make sure you learn C# not VB.  C# is much more marketable.

Answer (score 8):

I am by no means a tax professional, which is who you should probably ask, but from I understand about tax law:
 - If it is for a class or some other form of formal education, then yes, it can be written off. 
 - If you just teaching yourself a new skill, then no, it can't be written off.

but like Bryan Denny said, if you are just learning, you can get the [express edition for free](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx).

Comment: +1 for mentioning express edition. Also see http://www.microsoft.com/express - you don't even need DreamSpark verification, etc. The express edition is free for everyone.

Comment: As an update starting with vs 2013 there is a community edition which has more features than express.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about taxes on this issue, but you might be able to save some money!

Are you a student?  Checkout the DreamSpark program from Microsoft and get it for free [here](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx). Additionally, your school might have a MSDN license or be able to get you a copy for cheaper than retail.

Alternatively, there is also the free express edition if you don't need the features of the professional edition.

Comment: Well that's a step in the right direction...

Comment: +1 for express edition. Also see http://www.microsoft.com/express

Answer (score 2):

If you are currently employed as a programmer or similar job, you may be able to deduct the cost of Visual Studio, if it is part of a professional development program and exceeds 2% of your income.

Comment: What does the 2% mean?  2% of my yearly income?

Comment: Yes 2% annual income. You need to be very careful about this and talk to a tax professional or consult a tax guide. The IRS is pretty aggressive at disallowing these sorts of deductions.